# Move to another view controller using prepareForSegue: sender: or tableView: didSelectedRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I'm now building up a Core Data-based iOS application and I want an user to tap a cell in UITableViewController, which is based on Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController, to make him move to another view controller and he can see the detailed items there.

In iOS Master-Detail template application, when an user taps any cells then the view controller moves to detail view controller using storyboard segue to show the detailed items.

However, I don't know why this method, `prepareForSegue: sender:`, can respond to the user's tap and be called to move to detail view. If you're using UITableView, there are also one delegate method named `tableView: didSelecteRowAtIndexPath:`, which should exactly react to the user's tap action.

Actually, when I tried to write the latter method in order to move to detail view controller, the transition failed since I apparently called both methods simultaneously.

So my question is, 1) how can the `prepareForSegue: sender:` method respond to an user's tap action and correspondingly process its internal implementation, and 2) if I can use both `prepareForSegue: sender:` and `tableView: didSelecteRowAtIndexPath:`, which one should I use?

Whatever ways to take, I want to use NSFetchedResultsController to fetch the tapped cell's detailed data from Persistent Store, and display them in the detailed view controller. If that's the case, then where should I write the fetched code (either within the either method above, or the detail view controller's `viewDidLoad:` method) ?

I use iOS 7 and Xcode 5. Thanks.

Comment: Deleted my answer because the confusion on method names made my answer completely off-base.  I'll post a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hook your segue up from one view controller to another, rather than directly from a UI element, you can use `performSegue:withIdentifier:` to perform the segue exactly when you need it to be performed.

So in the case of a table view seguing into some other view, in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, you're going to grab some data from the selected row an prepare it for sending to the destination view controller.

Then at the end of this, you call `performSegue:withIdentifer:`.

As part of the segue process, `prepareForSegue:sender:` is called (in this case, called on the original table view controller).  Within this method, you have a reference to the origin view controller (via `self`) and the destination view controller (via `[segue destinationViewController]`), so it is within this method that you pass data from `self` to `[segue destinationViewController]`.

Essentially, you should be using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to handle any row selection logic and prepare the data you want to pass (save it to an `@property` perhaps), then in `prepareForSegue`, you perform all the logic required for passing the data.

Comment: Thanks. But my question is, HOW can the `prepareForSegue: sender:` method perceive an user's tap action? At what timing is the method called upon? I don't write ANY code to recognize the user's tap action, such as `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndex:`, but the segue functions well by using `prepareForSegue: sender:` method. I'd like to know why this method can perceive the user's tap and start to process accordingly.

Comment: `prepareForSegue:sender:` isn't perceiving the user's tap.  `prepareForSegue:sender:` is being called because something else perceived the users tap and is performing the segue.  `prepareForSegue` is called because the segue is about to happen.  If it's happening without you explicitly calling `performSegue:` in your code, then it's happening because you hooked the segue up to a UI element in your interface builder, rather than from the view controller itself.

Comment: So the iOS SDK or something in lower-level automatically connects the user's tap action on UITableViewCell to the storyboard segue, and I don't have to mind it, right?

Comment: If YOU connected the storyboard segue from a UI element such as a tableview or a button, then Xcode basically automatically calls the segue whenever that UI element is tapped and `prepareForSegue` is called as a result of the segue happening.

Comment: Ah, oops. I forgot about UITableViewCell by default being segue-connected when I start Master-Detail application. I got it, thanks a lot for your great clarification!